# Specific class for home link

Tags: wordpress

I just want to know how to add a specific class to the "home" link in wordpress.

Actually all the li has something like class="page_item page-item-XXXXX" where XXXXX is a number but the "home" link has no class.

Can I fix that ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add custom classes to menu items using the following in your functions.php

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'fkp_special_nav_class', 10, 2);
function fkp_special_nav_class($classes, $item)
{
  if($item->title == 'Home or what ever'){
    $classes[] = 'myCusomClass';
  }
  return $classes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in your `functions.php`

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'add_extra_class' , 10 , 2);
function add_extra_class($classes, $item){
    if($item->title == 'Home'){ // In this case your Home page's title should be 'Home'
        $classes[] = 'my_home_class';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```